# Styling multi-line button commands in Maya scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I'm writing my first toolkit in Maya, using Python and have come across a styling issue. When I have multi-line button commands, I have used the triple quote wrapping. However, to avoid getting “unexpected indentation” errors, I have had to strip all the styling indentation that makes the script more readable. I'm sure there is some nifty trick I'm just not aware of, so could somebody point me in the right direction?

Example from my code:

```
    form = cmds.formLayout(numberOfDivisions=3)
    add_button = cmds.button(label="Add Selected", command="""
selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)
list = cmds.text('attachToList', query=True, label=True)
split_list = list.split(', ')
split_list[0] = split_list[0].replace('Attach to: ', '')
list_items = split_list
for each in selection:
        if not each in list_items:
            list_items.append(each)
for each in list_items:
    if each == "":
        split_list.remove(each)
attachToList = cmds.text('attachToList', edit=True, label='Attach to: ' + ', '.join(list_items))""")

    remove_button = cmds.button(label="Remove Selected", command="""
selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)
list = cmds.text('attachToList', query=True, label=True)
split_list = list.split(', ')
split_list[0] = split_list[0].replace('Attach to: ', '')
list_items = split_list
for each in cmds.ls(sl=True):
    if each in list_items:
        list_items.remove(each)
attachToList = cmds.text('attachToList', edit=True, label='Attach to: ' + ', '.join(list_items))""")

    clear_button = cmds.button(label="Clear", command="cmds.text('attachToList', edit=True, label='Attach to: ')")

    cmds.formLayout(form, edit=True, attachForm=[(add_button, "left", 5), (clear_button, "right", 5)],
                    attachPosition=[(add_button, "right", 2, 1), (remove_button, "left", 2, 1),
                                    (remove_button, "right", 2, 2), (clear_button, "left", 2, 2)])

    cmds.setParent("..")
```

Comment: If you define functions for each item, `command=my_func` will likely work. Personally I'd suggest use `PySide2` for coding GUIs, You're using Maya's wrapper of it (eg. `cmds.button` is built on top of `PySide.QtWidgets.QPushButton`), which personally I've found to be really limited.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I guess I should probably write them into functions instead. I intended just a couple of command lines and then it went on a bit further...
I've not looked into PySide yet, so perhaps that will come later. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: Btw, I know Maya allows it, but generally speaking, it's bad practice to write code out like this as text. You should probably get used to using `lambda` for single lines, or functions for anything else.